# Warning: include_once(headerSite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache

I am new to PHP and am getting these errors

> Warning: include_once(headerSite.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbtest\index.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'headerSite.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbtest\index.php on line 3

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and learn how to write a good question. You should at least post the code of your index.php. Does any file headerSite.php exist? Where is it stored?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. As such your question is off topic

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `headerSite.php` file into 2 single quotation to be:

```
 include_once('headerSite.php');
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507